# Event Not Firing, Issues Communicating Between React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Forgive me for my naivety, but I'm rather new to React, and I've run into a bit of a snag. I have two related components that I need to communicate between. I have a 'Dropdown' Component that represents an option element (actually a div), and I need the value of that to cause a state change for a different Component. The dropdown should basically set the category in the state of a second component that will display different content based on category. I've tried several methods for handling this with very little success. Currently I'm trying to use EventListeners to handle this, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Below is my current code, and the way things are setup now I get an error saying:

> 'this.dispatchEvent is not a function'.

If someone  could help me solve that issue and move forward that would be so very much appreciated. Alternatively if this is a bad way to handle this I'm very open to suggestions.

```
var GridView = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    return {
      data: [],
      page: 0,      //for pagination
      loadingFlag: false,
    };
    },

  getMainFeed: function() {
...

   }, //end function
   getMoreItems: function() {
...

 }, //end function
 getFilteredItems: function() {
...
}, //end function
  componentWillMount: function() {

  },
  listenForEmailChange: function() {
    window.addEventListener("selectedFilterChange", this.handleFilterChange, false);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener("selectedFilterChange", this.handleFilterChange, false);
  },
  handleFilterChange: function(filter) {
   //Convert Data for getFilteredItems
   switch (filter.detail.filterType) {
    case 'category':
      this.setState({
        itemCategory: filter.detail.filterSelected,
      });
      break;
    case 'event':
      this.setState({
        eventType: filter.detail.filterSelected,
      });
      break;
    case 'type':
      if (0){
        this.setState({
          filterBuy: 1,
          filterInspiration: 0,
        });
      }
      if (1){
        this.setState({
          filterBuy: 0,
          filterInspiration: 1,
        });
      }
      if (2){
        this.setState({
          filterBuy: 1,
          filterInspiration: 1,
        });
      }
      break;
    case 'trending':
      this.setState({
        itemCategory: filter.detail.filterSelected,
      });
      break;
   }

//   this.getFilteredItems();
 },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    //loading("on");
    this.getMainFeed();
    MasonryInit();
    this.listenForEmailChange();
  },
  handleScroll:function(e){
    //this function will be triggered if user scrolls
    ...
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    $('#grid-container').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $('#grid-container').masonry('reloadItems');
    $('#grid-container').masonry('layout');
    });
  },
  render: function() {
      return (
        <div id="feed-container-inner">
          <GridMain data={this.state.data} />
        </div>

      );
    }
  });


      var Dropdown = React.createClass({
        sendFilter: function(item) {
          dropdownChange = new CustomEvent("selectedFilterChange", {
            detail: {
              filterType: this.props.filterSelector,
              filterSelected: item.id,
            }
          });
          window.dispatchEvent(dropdownChange);
        },
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {
            listVisible: false,
            display: ""
          };
        },

        select: function(item) {
          this.props.selected = item;
          this.sendFilter(item);
        },

        show: function() {
          this.setState({ listVisible: true });
          document.addEventListener("click", this.hide);
        },

        hide: function() {
          this.setState({ listVisible: false });
          document.removeEventListener("click", this.hide);
        },

        render: function() {
          return <div className={"dropdown-container" + (this.state.listVisible ? " show" : "")}>
            <div className={"dropdown-display" + (this.state.listVisible ? " clicked": "")} onClick={this.show}>
              <span>{this.props.selected.name}</span>
              <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div className="dropdown-list">
              <div>
                {this.renderListItems()}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>;
        },

        renderListItems: function() {
          var categories = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < this.props.list.length; i++) {
            var category = this.props.list[i];
            categories.push(<div onClick={this.select.bind(null, category)}>
              <span>{category.name}</span>
              <i className="fa fa-check"></i>
            </div>);
          }
          return categories;
        }
      });

  var GridFilter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        categoryList: [{
          name: "Loading Categories"
        }],
        eventList: [{
          name: "Loading Events"
        }],
        typeList: [{name: "Inspiration + Shoppable", id: 0}, {name: "Inspiration", id: 1}, {name: "Shoppable", id: 2}
        ],
        trendingList: [{
          name: "Loading Trending"
        }]

     };
    },
    getCategories: function() {

...

     }, //end function
     getEvents: function() {
...
      }, //end function
      getTrending: function() {

        ...

       }, //end function
    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.getCategories();
      this.getEvents();
      this.getTrending();
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div id="filter-bar" className="stamp">
          <Dropdown filterSelector={'category'} list={this.state.categoryList} selected={this.state.categoryList[0]} />
          <Dropdown filterSelector={'event'} list={this.state.eventList} selected={this.state.eventList[0]} />
          <Dropdown filterSelector={'type'} list={this.state.typeList} selected={this.state.typeList[0]} />
          <Dropdown filterSelector={'trending'} list={this.state.trendingList} selected={this.state.trendingList[0]} />
          <p className="filter-text">Filters:</p>

        </div>
      );
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

First, `this.dispatchEvent` does not exist in React. The way you "dispatch an event" is by passing a `function` as a prop and then calling it. Your `dropdown` component should have a `onSelect` prop that is a function. Whenever the user selects something, just call `this.props.onSelect` passing the appropriate parameters.

Second, you should never set a `prop` as you are doing on your `select` method. If you want to store the value of your selected item within the component, you should use state.

A refactored version of your `select` method would be something like this:

```
  select: function(item) {
    this.setState({selected: item });
    if(this.onSelect) {
        this.onSelect(/* pass args here */);
    }
  }
```

The rest of your code should probably be refactored because of the change above, this is just for clarity.

Bonus tip: Be aware of the concept of `controlled` vs. `uncontrolled` components.

**Controlled components**: Components that store little to none state. They just trigger events when something changes and it is responsability of the parent component to rerender it passing the appropriate `props`. In your case, if your component is acting as `controlled`, it would not hold the state of the selected item, it would only trigger the `onSelect` event and the parent would rerender it passing the new selected item as a prop.

**Uncontrolled components**: Components that will work by themselves, without attaching handlers. In your case, if your component is acting as `uncontrolled`, even though it *could* have an `onSelect` event, it would keep the state of the selected item in such a way that it would work without attaching any event handler. It would rerender itself when something changes.

Usually components are designed to be either `controlled` or `uncontrolled`, but it's possible to have a mix of them.

Comment: Thanks for all the good info. I'm going to try your suggestions. I tried to implement your refactored select method, but now the initially selected item isn't showing up. Before I set the initially selected item on the dropdown through '<Dropdown list={this.state.categoryList} selected={this.state.categoryList[0]} />' How would I pass this if it's now a state?

Comment: Also, regarding this part 'Whenever the user selects something, just call this.props.onSelect passing the appropriate parameters.' How will that change the state of other components though? It sounds like you are talking about within this Component, but I need the dropdown Component to change the state of the GridView Component.

Comment: Regarding this: '<Dropdown list={this.state.categoryList} selected={this.state.categoryList[0]} />' I would suggest that you pass the selected index, and not the whole object. I did not get this part: How would I pass this if it's now a state?

Comment: @BillWalters, regarding your second comment: Imagine that your dropdown is uncontrolled. Now you have a wrapper component that renders the dropdown and the grid. Now, within the wrapper, assign an event handler to the dropdown, when it changes, change the `selectedSomething` state of the wrapper. That will trigger the wrapper's render again. Now render the dropdown passing it as the selected item and render the grid according to it too.

Comment: I updated the code above so hopefully things make more sense now. Regarding your first comment, I have some questions. How would I display the list of categories without passing the entire list? And what I meant about passing it now that it's state is that now that I changed 'selected' from a prop to a state the initially selected category doesn't show up.

Comment: Regarding the second comment. How would I do that if the grid and the dropdown aren't in the same wrapper? That's why I setup the EventListeners, which are working now thankfully. I appreciate your help, as I'm trying to learn the right way of using React, and clearly having some hiccups.